# How to update tableview cell content in realtime whenever the content of cell is updated in realtime in ios swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, cocoa, cocoa-touch

I am working on chat application using openfire, I have put a delivery status label inside a tableview cell. I am getting a call back whether the receiver received message or not and then I am updating delivery status to sqlite DB, and then I am displaying the content of cell. 
My problem is that my delivery status label is not updating after sqlite update when the user is in that tableviewcontroller in realtime.

Answer (score 0):

Update your model data and then call the table view's `reloadRows(at:with:)` method with the indexPaths of the cell(s) that changed. Make sure to issue the call to `reloadRows(at:with:)` on the main thread.

Comment: If you're going to update **every** row you're better off calling `reloadData()`, which reloads the entire table view. There's also `reloadSections(_:with:)` that will reload a set of entire sections.

Comment: I have used reloadData() but still the tableview is not getting reloaded when the user in that viewcontroller.